# How to change du recursion order

Tags: shell-script, disk-usage, coreutils

I've looked into sorting the result of `du` before and only ever seen suggestions to `sort` the result such as `du | sort`.

This is acceptable for most uses but it is specifically unhelpful when listing multiple directories with hardlinks.  For example I have an incremental backup:

If `du` doubly count's hard links the content looks like this

```
# du -hl --max-depth 1 /backup/saturn/ | sort -k 2
3.2G    /backup/saturn/
456M    /backup/saturn/2017-05-19
458M    /backup/saturn/2017-05-20
461M    /backup/saturn/2017-05-21
464M    /backup/saturn/2017-05-22
462M    /backup/saturn/2017-05-23
462M    /backup/saturn/2017-05-24
465M    /backup/saturn/2017-05-25
```

But these results aren't true because each dated dir shares a lot of hard links to other dir's files.... It's an incremental backup.

But the more meaningful result looks like this.

```
# du -h --max-depth 1 /backup/saturn/ | sort -k 2
666M    /backup/saturn/
29M     /backup/saturn/2017-05-19
53M     /backup/saturn/2017-05-20
25M     /backup/saturn/2017-05-21
40M     /backup/saturn/2017-05-22
462M    /backup/saturn/2017-05-23
14M     /backup/saturn/2017-05-24
46M     /backup/saturn/2017-05-25
```

This is a little nonsensical because it has evaluated the dirs in an arbitrary order and so gives much less meaningful information on how much has changed from one date to the next.

So I'm looking for a way to control the order `du` evaluates directories.

Comment: If you sort the list in advance, you can have `du` to respect that; e.g. `du -hs $(ls -tr /backup/saturn)`, which will sort according to the age of the folders.

Comment: For more hints, see the conversation in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360856/how-to-get-the-accurate-real-size-of-backup-directories

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [ridgy's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367197/how-to-change-du-recursion-order#comment652379_367197), newer versions of `du` can read a list of files to scan using the `--files0-from` option, so you could do:

```
printf "%s\0" /backup/saturn/*/ | sort -z | du --files0-from=- -h --total
```

For example:

```
$ du -hxd1 foo
111M    foo/2017-05-20
4.0K    foo/2017-05-19
4.0K    foo/2017-05-30
111M    foo
```

And:

```
$ printf "%s\0" foo/*/ | sort -z | du --files0-from=- -h --total
101M    foo/2017-05-19/
11M     foo/2017-05-20/
4.0K    foo/2017-05-30/
111M    total
```

You can use `find` if there are too many files to glob for `printf`, but it's a bit verbose:

```
$ find foo -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | sort -z | du --files0-from=- -h --total
101M    foo/2017-05-19
11M     foo/2017-05-20
4.0K    foo/2017-05-30
111M    total
```